# Periodically getting "A generic error occurred in GDI+"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gdi+, memorystream

I will appreciate any help. This is a very famous issue, but whatever I read and tried to apply to my specific case, it did not help.

I have a simple function, which takes an image as a base64 string and saves it as a png image. The destination folder is constant. The filename is taken from the imageUrl parameter and is made unique before saving.

```
public static void SaveWorkOrderImage(string imageData, string imageUrl)
{
    try
    {
        //convert png image saved in a base64 string to Image object
        imageData = imageData.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "");
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);

        //...
        //some code here which generates the destination path for the new image
        //...

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            using (System.Drawing.Image newData = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms))
            {
                using (Bitmap bmpData = new Bitmap(newData))
                {
                    bmpData.Save(destPath, ImageFormat.Png);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //processing and logging exception
    }
}
```

This code runs just fine as MVC application in IIS. But suddenly in about a week of perfect working it starts throwing the following exception for every image that is saved:

Exception Type: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException
Exception: A generic error occurred in GDI+.
Stack Trace: 
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)

If I restart the App Pool, then it again works normally for several days. Usually about a week. Then everything repeats again. It looks like some resources are not being disposed, or there is an overflow of some buffer. But, as you can see, there is a "using" statement for each disposable object. 
I also tried to convert it first to a Bitmap (I found such an advise in the similar question). It looked like this before:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    using (System.Drawing.Image newData = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms))
    {
        newData.Save(destPath, ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

It did not help however.

Comment: Please remove the `catch (Exception ex)` and try again without exception handling. It could be that exceptions are occasionally holding resources. If you are going to catch any exceptions they should **specific** exceptions (never `Exception`) and that you can **recover** from.

Comment: You mention IIS. Pretty much all image processing in the `System.Drawing` namespace is explicitly unsupported in web environments due to GDI+ limitations.